# Return content of read-only <input type=text>

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ifld1014" class="ax-terminal-field x20" title="" style="top: 272px;
left: 154px;"><input type="text" maxlength="30" size="30" 
class="ax-terminal-inputField ax_x20i" readonly="readonly" style="width: 240px;"></div>
```

Here is some of my casper code:

```js
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
....//truncated for shortness//....
    casper.echo(x('//*[@id="ifldf14"]/input').value);
```

The result in undefined. I tried .value, .text, .innerHTML, but they all come up undefined when run. How do I get the content of the input field?

Comment: Are you sure the `id` is not dynamically generated and is always `ifld1014`?

Comment: When I dump with    utils.dump(x('//*[@id="ifld1014"]/input'));    I don't get anything other than type and path. Any ideas?

Comment: And what value were you expecting? From your code, your `input` has an undefined value. You tried `input.value` and it rightly gave you `undefined`.

Comment: On the screen, there is text in the readonly input. Im trying to return the value contained. This is coming from a web-based terminal emulator system for which I am building an API. The screen loads with content in the input which I am trying to return.

Comment: Your doc is not well-formed. The element input has no closing tag.

Comment: I can not control the document itself as it's hosted by the service provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was not using jQuery to get my value out. Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 1):

## DOM context

CasperJS a sandboxed DOM context (page context). It is only there where you can access DOM elements directly. The page context is inside of the [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) callback. Everything else about a DOM element is only a representation of it, because DOM nodes cannot be passed to the outside context.

## Accessing input value

There are a lot of ways to get information out of the DOM, but DOM nodes cannot be printed to the console as-is. Here are two ways to get the input value.

1. You can use `casper.evaluate()`. Since you want to use an XPath expression, you can use [`__utils__.getElementByXPath()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#getelementbyxpath) helper function that is injected by CasperJS into the page:

   ```
   var value = casper.evaluate(function(xpathexpr){
       return __utils__.getElementByXPath(xpathexpr).value;
   }, '//*[@id="ifldf14"]/input');
   casper.echo("value: " + value);
   ```
2. If the input field is inside of a form and if the element has a name attribute, then you can use [`casper.getFormValues()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getformvalues) and get the value using the name of the field.

   ```
   casper.echo(casper.getFormValues('form').nameHere);
   ```

## XPath helper utility

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
```

Is only a little helper that transforms a string to an object with the properties `type` and `path`. It's only used in CasperJS internally to represent XPaths. The distinction is necessary, because CasperJS supports both CSS selectors and XPath expressions. Both of them are simple strings initially, but are executed differently.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The first method yields NULL, and when I dump the value with utils.dump, I still get NULL:                    utils.dump(casper.evaluate(function(xpathexpr){
    return __utils__.getElementByXPath(xpathexpr);
   }, '//*[@id="ifldf14"]/input'));

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot of the page to see if you're on the correct page? Have you surrounded this code with casper.then() ? As I said you cannot pass DOM nodes out if the page context.

Comment: I took a screenshot, the input has data, but not from the source. I think its adding the context in a javascript function after load, I waited a few seconds, and still get null values. I tried wrapping in a casper.then()

Comment: *the input has data, but not from the source* What does that mean? Does it have a placeholder? If yes, the placeholder doesn't appear as the input value. Can you provide a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of your full and minimal code?